# Specify floating point precision in GDB

Tags: c++, floating-point, gdb

I am debugging a C++ application and when I display a double-precision floating point number in GDB I get a result like:`.035449094393`

How do I display more decimal places? Ideally I would be able to specificy the precision and get a result like: `.0354490943927692`

Basically, I am attempting to find the reason for a very minor difference between 2 variables. If I use printf with a format specifier like `%1.20f` I can see the difference in the variables but not using GDB.

Comment: it doesnt make much sense to print more digits than the number actually has significant digits

Comment: That is the problem. The variable has many more significant digits and I want GDB to show them to me.

Comment: many more than 16?? What data type is that?

Comment: Physics related data and extreme precision is important in my particular use case. My example numbers might not have been ideal as I am often looking at very small numbers (below 1).

Comment: Are you using an external library for this data type?

Comment: is it a `double`? You wont get much more than 16 digits out of that....

Comment: No external libraries (none available). C++ double variables.

Comment: "I am often looking at very small numbers" dont confuse number of significant digits with very small/big numbers. Eg `1.23e30` and `5.4e-20` arent a problem on their own, but if you want to add them you are out of luck concerning precision with `double`s

Comment: btw GDB is likely already showing you **all** the significant digits. If you really need more you need to use some high/arbitrary precision data type (which `double` is not really)

Comment: ...are you comparing two floating points with `==` and now try to find out why two equal values arent equal?

Comment: Interesting, I am just confused as to why I can see the difference using printf (see my edit). Eventually the small difference in the variable ripples up to a bigger difference in another variable which is obvious in GDB.

Comment: I am not comparing floating points using `==`. Comparing two separate applications with common code trying to determine why they yield nearly identical (but not exactly the same) results.

Comment: gdb does display more decimal places, you can test it yourself: `(gdb) p .035449094393
$1 = 0.035449094393000001`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, GDB's `p/f <variable>` has limited precision.

You can use `printf` to show more decimal places:

```
(gdb) printf "%1.20f\n", <variable>
```

<sup>However, it is very likely that at this point you will start running into the limitations of your data type (there may be rounding errors and other small deviations from what you might expect as a value).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can do `call printf("%.10f\n", d)` in `gdb` and it will print it in `stdout` with the desired format.